# Google-Maps-for-Rails Direction Wiki Explaination Needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Hi I am currently working on a trash bin/recycling bin location application using google maps for rails.

I have a recyclingbin.rb model with the address as its attributes, that itself is enough to put markers on a map that can get displayed using the gem. I believe the gem converts the model and its attributes into json data.

I am trying to implement a feature where I can input my location and get direction to the nearest marker.

I have looked at the wiki , https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Direction

Am I suppose to put this in the view ?

{ "data" => { "from" => "Paris, france", "to" => "Toulon, france" } }
            })
 %>

with the from to be embedded with my location for now? I understand I can pass options to this reference from google.

The wiki is quite short, can someone give me a quick explanation ?

Answer (score 2):

The wiki does need some more work. I have a simple app working that shows the directions on the map from a location to another (pre-defined) location

```
<%= gmaps("map_options" => {"zoom" => 14}, "markers" => { "data" => @json },
"direction"   => { "data" => {"from" => @location.address, "to" => "New York City"},"travelMode" => "DRIVING"}) %>
```

I just put this in my view. It shouldn't matter where, just as long as its there. Hope this helps